# gitx(L): view files that need committing

Tags: gitx

In gitx(L), is it possible to view all the files that need to be committed?

For example, it would be handy to have a pane that shows the list of files that have changes. However, I can't seem to see one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Off topic, this GitX is more actively maintained than Laullion one: http://rowanj.github.io/gitx/

Answer (score 0):

You can find this list in the staging dialog, accessible from the upper left corner. You'll see the classic Git commit, with a list of changed or untracked files, and the ability to stage and commit them.